# VIM custom syntax school of rock

Tags: vim, guitar

I try to compact some chord files and then need to highlight some stuff so it is more visual. This syntax is where chord is followed by a comma then a number showing how many beats, and all surrounded in curly brackets. Here is the example from a classic rock song you might have heard:

```
{Dm,4}Don't cry, don't {C/D,4}raise your eye
It's {Bb/D,2}on-ly {Am,2} teen-age {Dm,4hold}waste-land
```

I simply want to make the chord names one color, and the time notation another color... In a nutshell that's everything between { and next , as one color then up to the next } as a second color. Maybe the brackets should be another color too. I suck at regular expressions but this forum can point me in right direction to eventually master them I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple version that will just highlight the whole `{...}` blocks. Put the following in `${HOME}/.vim/syntax/rock.vim`:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syntax match rockNotation      "{[^}]*}"

highlight link rockNotation    String
```

And the following in `${HOME}/.vim/ftdetect/rock.vim`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rock set filetype=rock
```

Now whenever you open a `.rock` file, the chords should be highlighted. (If detection doesn't work, try to set `:set filetype=rock` manually, see if it changes something.) Note that if you edited these files from Vim, you may need to restart it for the effects to apply.

Here is a longer version, where chords and time indications are highlighted in different colors:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syntax clear
syntax case match

setlocal iskeyword+=#                                                                         
setlocal iskeyword+=-
setlocal iskeyword+=+

syntax match rockChord /\<[A-G]\(b\|#\)\=\(m\|-\|dim\|+\|aug\|7\|m7\|Maj7\|m7b5\)\=\(\/[A-G]\(b\|#\)\=\)\=\>/ contained
syntax match rockDuration /[1-9][0-9]*\(hold\|mute\)\=/ contained

syntax region rockAnnotRegion start=/{/ end=/}/ contains=rockChord,rockDuration

highlight link rockChord          Type
highlight link rockDuration       Constant
highlight link rockAnnotRegion    Delimiter
```

As you can see, my regexp for chords got a little wild. It supports things like `A#m7b5/Db`, which of course makes little sense (and sounds horrible), but you get the idea.

Comment: I will play around with the regexp since some of my chords are represented a little less generic but this is good to go! Thanx!

Comment: by the way, in setting this up I found some \syntax\chordpro.vim . . . but it's probably a little too elaborate for my rock files . . . will check that next tho